# Nothing happens on command prompt when i Run dotnet run command as shown in image

Tags: api, .net-core, command-line-interface

[image]

To Solve this issue i have to restart the PC everytime this happens. After restarting PC dotnet run command executes successfully as shown below.
[image]

Comment: What does the directory you're in look like? Does it have `.dll` files or `.csproj`/`.fsproj`/`.vbproj` files?

Comment: Directory having .csproj file. Sometimes dotnet run command run sometime s give above issue.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include more detail, such as what it looks like when it is working? I don't think we can reproduce this issue as-is.

Comment: Sure for that let me restart the PC. Updated the question with screenshot.

Comment: this has just happened to my on my macbook using the dotnet CLI 5.0